# classic asp use capicom for md5 hashing - result differs from .net System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, hash, asp-classic, md5

When using CAPICOM in Classic ASP (VBScript) to perform MD5 hashing like so:

```
With server.CreateObject("CAPICOM.HashedData")
    .Algorithm = 3                  ' CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_MD5
    .Hash "password"

    md5Pwd = .Value
End With
```

I get this result: `B081DBE85E1EC3FFC3D4E7D0227400CD`

When I use .NET, I get this result: `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`

Why are the MD5 strings different? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my C# function:

```
MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash( Encoding.Default.GetBytes( val ) );

StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

// Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
// and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
for( int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++ ) {
    sBuilder.Append( data[i].ToString( "x2" ) );
}

// Return the hexadecimal string.
return sBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Encoding.Default` encoding which [represents 7 bit ASCII characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx). At the same time, “[CAPICOM manipulates only Unicode strings while validating and generating digital signatures](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/CapicomUTF8.aspx)”.

So, `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` deals with one-byte characters (losing any non-ASCII data by the way), while CAPICOM.HashedData treats them as 2-byte Unicode characters.

Replace `Encoding.Default` with `Encoding.Unicode` to make your .NET implementation to be compatible with CAPICOM.

One more note, use `data[i].ToString("X2")` to produce upper-case result, as you have in CAPICOM implementation.